# LinkedList.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: java, linked-list

> LinkedList.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

I am getting this message when I compile my `LinkedList` class. I am assuming it has something to do with me using generics incorrectly, but I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code for the Node class and the Linked List class.

---

Node.java

```
public class Node<T> {

    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node() {
        this.data = null;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

}
```

---

LinkedList.java

```
public class LinkedList<T> {

    private Node<T> head;

    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    public LinkedList(Node<T> head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public void add(T data) {
        if(this.isEmpty())
            this.head = new Node<>(data, null);

        else {
            Node<T> current = this.head;
            while(current.getNext() != null)
                current = current.getNext();
            current.setNext(new Node<>(data, null));
        }
    }

    public T remove() {
        Node<T> current = this.head;
        Node<T> follow = null;

        while(current.getNext() != null) {
            follow = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        if(follow == null)
            this.head = null;
        else
            follow.setNext(null);

        return current.getData();
    }

    public int size() {
        Node current = this.head;
        int count = 0;
        while(current != null) {
            count++;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public boolean contains(T data) {
        boolean result = false;

        Node current = this.head;
        while(current != null) {
            if(current.getData() == data)
                result = true;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (this.head == null);
    }

    public String toString() {
        if(this.isEmpty())
            return "[]";

        String output = "[";
        Node<T> current = this.head;
        while(current != null) {
            output += current.getData();
            if(current.getNext() != null)
                output += ", ";
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        output += "]";
        return output;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code causes the compilation warnings:

> ```
> public Node getNext() {
>     return this.next;
> }
> ```

when you do operations like:

> ```
> current = current.getNext();
> ```

when `current` is declared as:

> ```
> Node<T> current;
> ```

`getNext` should be:

```
public Node<T> getNext() {
    return this.next;
}
```

And all occurrences of `Node` should be `Node<T>`.

Comment: Thank you! You and Eran helped me understand.

Answer (score 1):

There are some places where you use the raw `Node` type (`size()` and `contains()` methods) :

```
Node current = this.head;
```

Change it to

```
Node<T> current = this.head;
```

`Node getNext()` should also be changed to `Node<T> getNext()`.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks a lot! Just curious, why would using a raw type be considered bad?

Comment: @zaynv It's considered bad because it prevents the compiler from doing type checking that would make your code more type safe. A raw Node can contain any type of data. a `Node<T>` used inside `LinkedList<T>` can only contain data of the type used to instantiate the `LinkedList<T>`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to answer!